# In Sublime Text 2, how can I remove all double blank lines?

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, sublimetext

In Sublime Text 2, how can I take all instances of double blank lines and change them to single blank lines?

I want this:

```
foo


bar


foo
```

...to become this:

```
foo

bar

foo
```

Edit: I understand this question is very basic, but I posted it hoping to help others out because I did not see an answer on SO. If I've made a mistake in doing so, please let me know how I can improve.

Comment: Try  `^[\s]*?[\n\r]+` for empty lines along with whitespaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out.

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> (Find -> Replace)
2. Enable regular expressions (.* button)
3. Find What: `\n\n\n` for newlines only or `\n[ \t]*\n[ \t]*\n` to match blank lines that may include spaces and/or tabs.
4. Replace With: `\n\n`
5. Use Find, Replace, and Replace All buttons as desired.

Note: If you use Replace All, three or more consecutive blank lines will ***not*** be replaced by one blank line as may be expected.

Comment: Yep.  RegExp rocks!  Good job in figuring this out.